# Insert Command in Zend Framework using DBTable

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

I am new in Zend Framework

This is my DBTable

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Employee extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

protected $_name = 'tab_employee';
}
```

This is my Models

```
public function InsertEmployees($array){
   $tblEmployee = new Application_Model_DbTable_Employee();
   $tblEmployee->insert($array);
}
```

This is my controller

```
 public function AddEmployeeAction(){
 $request = $this->getRequest();
 $params = $request->getParams();
 $emp = new Application_Model_InsEmployee();
 $emp->InsertEmployees(array(
          'Name' => $params['name'],
          'Date' => $params['date']
 ));
}
```

Anybody knows what is the error of this code because it always return an application error . Thanks for advance

Comment: Can you tell us what the application error says? Are the column names (Name, Date) same as the columns in your tab_employee table?

Answer (score 0):

In your DbTable do this:

```
public function InsertEmployees($array){
   $this->insert($array);
}
```

So your DB will look like this:

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Employee extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

  protected $_name = 'tab_employee';

  public function InsertEmployees($array){
    $this->insert($array);
  }
}
```

Then from the controller, create the DbTable instance and "bypass" the model.

```
$model = new Application_Model_Db_Table();
$model->InsertEmployees($data)
```